# cordova-camera-plugin error java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: cordova, phonegap, genymotion, numberformatexception, cordova-plugin-camera

I am developing a cordova application that i run in genymotion emulator. If i select normal images taken with the emulator camera everything works fine. When i try to select some images that i imported in the emulator drag-dropping them, the app crashes with error

```
Process: com.phonegap.helloworld, PID: 1973
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/provaa.jpg"
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:590)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:804)
    at org.apache.cordova.camera.FileHelper.getRealPathFromURI_API11_And_Above(FileHelper.java:101)
    at org.apache.cordova.camera.FileHelper.getRealPath(FileHelper.java:60)
    at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.processResultFromGallery(CameraLauncher.java:682)
    at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.access$000(CameraLauncher.java:74)
    at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher$1.run(CameraLauncher.java:830)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

The code for select images is

```
 function selectImage(){
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
    });

    function onSuccess(imageData) {
        let image = document.getElementById('myImage');     
        image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        imagepost= imageData;            
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to solve?

Comment: This is a known bug in cordova-plugin-camera:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/pull/322


The fix is already merged, but not released yet.